# Stopping an inner loop after one correct iteration

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, break

The problem in the code is in the goldbach method. I want to stop iteration of the inner two loops after the inner most loop has found one pair of numbers, but I am not getting how to exit just those two loops. In other words, I only want to find only one pair per i integer created by the outermost for loop, and then move on to the next integer i.

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// finding prime numbers using sieve of Eratosthenes and golbach's conjecture
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] num = new int[1000000];

        for (int i = 2; i <= num.length; i++) {
            num[i - 1] = i;
        }
        Test.sieve(num);


        Test.goldbach(num);
    }
    public static void sieve(int[] array) {

        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(array.length); i++) {
            if (array[i - 1] == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = 2 * i; j <= array.length; j += i) {
                array[j - 1] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] != 0) {
                //System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }


    public static void goldbach(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i += 2) { //to go through every even integer
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                    System.out.println("two prime numbers that add to " + i + " are " + array[j] + " and " + array[k]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there no `if` condition inside `k` loop? That will not work at all... You will only get k = 0 values for each `j` for each `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the value of j in your second loop. eg.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i += 2) { //to go through every even integer
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                System.out.println("two prime numbers that add to " + i + " are " + array[j] + " and "  + array[k]);
                j = i + 1; // This will end the outer loop as well.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a label to break (or continue) a loop other than the inner one:

```
    found:
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                System.out.println("two prime numbers that add to " + i + " are " + array[j] + " and "  + array[k]);
                break found;
            }
        }
    }
```

or use an additional method and return - more indicated if that new method has an own clear function (and *better* name)

```
public static void goldbach(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i += 2) { //to go through every even integer
        primeAdd(i);
    }
}

private static void primeAdd(int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.println("two prime numbers that add to " + i + " are " + array[j] + " and "  + array[k]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

but, as already commented by bureaquete, there is no need for the inner loop since it is always being terminated.